# Can the Bitcoin client be used without any incoming ports being opened?

Tags: security, bitcoind, ubuntu

I am running bitcoind on the latest Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal Quetzel on amazon's EC2 network.

The security group I have attached to the box only allows port 22 so I can login via ssh.

How is bitcoind able to operate, then?

I started up bitcoind and it says it has 8 connections and is actively downloading blocks... but how? When port 22 is the only opened port on my box?
-confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your firewall allows outgoing connections.

Bitcoind creates 8 outgoing connections (by default), over port 8333.

Comment: So I am currently leeching from the Bitcoin network, but not helping it propagate transactions? Is that correct?

Comment: @user3145: You are helping to propagate transactions between the 8 nodes you've made outbound connections to, but that's it. I believe the Bitcoin network has no capacity shortage though, so there's no need to go to special efforts to contribute.